# Handling \u200b (Zero width space) character in text preprocessing for NLP task

Tags: python, nlp, removing-whitespace, spacy

I'm preprocessing some text for a NER model I'm training, and I'm encountering this character quite a lot. This character is not removed with `strip()`:

```
>>> 'Hello world!\u200b'.strip()
'Hello world!\u200b'
```

It is not considered a whitespace for regular expressions:

```
>>> re.sub('\s+', ' ', "hello\u200bworld!")
'hello\u200bworld!'
```

and spaCy's tokenizer does not split tokens upon it:

```
>>> [t.text for t in nlp("hello\u200bworld!")]
['hello\u200bworld', '!']
```

So, how should I handle it? I can simply replace it, however I don't want to make a special case for this character, but rather replace all characters with similar characteristics.

Thanks.

Comment: The character's definition says it's specifically *not* a space or whitespace character. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm  If people are using it incorrectly, it's not really well-defined exactly what to do with it.  That's NLP for you ...

Comment: That is correct, but some of the text I'm preprocessing is extracted from a PDF using Apache Tika.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned, characters like `\u200b` *(zero-width space)* and `\u200c` *(zero-width non joiner)* are not considered as a space character. So, you cannot omit such characters using techniques available for space characters.
The only way, as you may have noticed, is to consider such characters as a special case.

Answer (score 3):

How about simply doing string replace before NLP?

```
'Hello world!\u200b'.replace('\u200b', ' ').strip()
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question: _I can simply replace it, however, I don't want to make a special case for this character, but rather replace all characters with similar characteristics_